# Using Butterknife to inject an array of views

Tags: android, butterknife

Currently I have this array of views:

```
ImageView activityImageViews[] = {
    (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.img_activity_1),
    (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.img_activity_2),
    (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.img_activity_3),
    (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.img_activity_4)
};
```

Is there a way I could use Butterknife to inject all those views? I need to keep them in an array (or in a way so I can iterate over them).

Comment: Just recently stumbled upon Butterknife so do not know if it supports that directly but why not just inject them individually and collect them in an array or a list inside onCreate?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Currently it is possible to inject several views as array. From ButterKnife [documentation](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) (see VIEW LISTS section)

```
@InjectViews({ R.id.first_name, R.id.middle_name, R.id.last_name })
List<EditText> nameViews;
```

Same thing for multiple click listeners:

```
@OnClick({ R.id.door1, R.id.door2, R.id.door3 })
public void pickDoor(DoorView door) {
  if (door.hasPrizeBehind()) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You win!", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  } else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Try again", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 2017-09-19**:
Since Butterknife version [Version 7.0.0 (2015-06-27)](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/d19d9ab6bead884798f747face552d6527777597/CHANGELOG.md#version-700-2015-06-27) `@Bind` replaced `@InjectView` and `@InjectViews`.
But since version [Version 8.0.0 (2016-04-25)](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/d19d9ab6bead884798f747face552d6527777597/CHANGELOG.md#version-800-2016-04-25) `@Bind` was replaced with `@BindView` and `@BindViews` for one view and multiple views, respectively.
So for now the correct syntax is:

```
@BindView(R.id.button1) Button button1;
@BindView(R.id.button2) Button button2;

@BindViews({ R.id.first_name, R.id.middle_name, R.id.last_name })
List<EditText> nameViews;
```

Comment: Cool! Even though I'm not working on that project anymore, it's good to know for future reference so thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that the elements added to the Array are dynamically, otherwise you can simply declare them in your header one by one and afterwards add them to the array:

```
// in the header:
@InjectView(R.id.imageview1) ImageView imageView1;
@InjectView(R.id.imageview2) ImageView imageView2;
@InjectView(R.id.imageview3) ImageView imageView3;

// inside your code:
ImageView activityImageViews[] = {
    imageView1, imageView2, imageView3
};
```

But however, if the elements are dynamic (in amount of elements/id of elements etc.) the only thing you can do is to use `ButterKnife.findById` which will spare the `ImageView` cast - you can't inject them via annotation because Butterknife does not know what to generate/inject on compile time (the information is first available on runtime).

```
ImageView activityImageViews[] = {
    ButterKnife.findById(view, R.id.img_activity_1),
    ButterKnife.findById(view, R.id.img_activity_2),
    ButterKnife.findById(view, R.id.img_activity_3),
    ButterKnife.findById(view, R.id.img_activity_4)
};
```

Comment: The second snippet gives _Incompatible types. Required: android.widget.ImageView, Found: android.view.View_. I'll use your first approach, thank you!

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. I use ButterKnife 4.0.1 and also the second approach works fine for me. The documentation says `[...]It uses generics to infer the return type and automatically performs the cast.`